# SQL Server : unsanitized user input with read only user

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, sql-injection

I created a simple page with HTML/PHP for the sole purpose of getting unsanitized user input.

It is located here: `http://109.201.140.29/mssql/`

I did this just for fun, I use this windows server for nothing else currently.

Is there any risk when the user ONLY has (readonly) access to the database test_db?

It also logs failed/successful queries, sample of error log (as you can see, drop table does not work):

```
[2014-07-08 14:27:41] (query) Execution of query: "DROP TABLE users;" Failed.
     src IP: <snip>
     err: SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot drop the table 'users', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

sample from successful queries log:

```
[2014-07-08 14:17:38] (query) Executed: "select * from users;".
     src IP: <snip>.
     Returned rows: 100.

[2014-07-08 14:17:45] (query) Executed: "select @@version;".
     src IP: <snip>.
     Returned rows: 1.

[2014-07-08 14:19:12] (query) Executed: "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables".
     src IP: <snip>.
     Returned rows: 1.
```

Simple question I suppose; but is there any risk here? Besides the obvious flaw of taking user input as queries..

The user has as I said read-only access and is not a owner of any databases.

I ask because this is my first experience with SQL Server, but from my testing at least the queries seem to only allow reading (`SELECT`) which is OK for this purpose.

Feel free to test queries of course - as there may be some queries possible that I am not aware of.

Comment: `EXEC xp_dirtree 'C:\'` gives me a result.... well half a result

Comment: Yeah I see it in the error log hehe, EDIT: I am also printing the caught exceptions wherever it fails. Hence half a result :)

Comment: Of course there's a risk, an attacker can see all the data contained in your database. Not to mention @ElectricLlama already has a dirtree.

Comment: Does DOS count as a bad thing? `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; BEGIN TRANSACTION; SELECT * from users WITH (XLOCK); WAITFOR DELAY '23:59:59'`

Comment: `select * from sys.syslogins`. These things do nothing on their own, they just increase that 'attack surface'

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever did you run that as it's hanging now?

Comment: Maybe I did. Maybe I've got a browser window that's been hanging for a while :-)

Comment: Hehe, yeah this VM has only 1GB of memory. I see someone from UK is making some huge one-liners. Fascinating to tail these log files.

Comment: @Tanner - I've closed it now - whether that will cause the back-end connection to be cleaned up in a timely manner depends on what the server does.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever its back up now. And yes DOS counts as a bad thing :)

Comment: hanging again... I'm going to have to do some work

Comment: If you allow "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries" (you do not) you would be open to a brute force attack to figure out the password for sa using `openrowset`.

Comment: I created a new database now named "internet_db" where executing user is owner. Can now do stuff like `use internet_db; create table hello_world( name varchar(MAX), comment varchar(MAX));` I guess this opens up the possibility to do more things :D will check back here/logs and internet_db tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Security is built from confidentiality, availability and integrity.
Confidentiality is obviously compromised as you just give any access.
Availability is compromised as Damien showed, and other methods can be also used.
Integrity is the only thing the the "read-only" permissions actually helps to protect, but it is also limited.
Your DB Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60, there are always new exploits that can give total server takeover, and if you give direct access to the DB an attacker can always perform brute force attack to guess and impersonate another stronger user or even admin user (EXECUTE AS LOGIN... for example).
You can never close all of the potential vulnerabilities and you should never allow any direct access to your DB.